# PHP upload and send file with cURL

Tags: php, wordpress, post, curl, filesystems

I'm attempting to upload a file to a WordPress installation and then send it, along with other data from other form fields, to [Lever's API](https://github.com/lever/postings-api).

I can send data to the endpoint just fine, but not so much with the file uploading. The following does in fact upload to wp-content/uploads, but I think the problem lies either on the next line `move_uploaded_file` or where I'm passing it in the `$data` array.

---

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/jobForm.php">
    <input type="file" name="resume">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

---

```
<?php
// URL
$url = "https://api.lever.co/v0/postings/XXXX/XXXXXX";

$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$urls = $_POST["urls"];

$target = "/www/wp-content/uploads/" . basename($_FILES["resume"]["name"]);

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["resume"]["tmp_name"], $target);

// data
$data = array(
    "name" => $name,
    "email" => $email,
    "urls" => $urls,
    "resume" => @$_FILES["resume"]
);

// initiate curl instance, set options, and post
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); // url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);                                                   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); // full data to post                                              
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // return results as a string instead of outputting directly                                                             

echo $data["resume"];
// $output 
$output = curl_exec($ch);  
var_dump($output);

// close curl resource to free up system resources 
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

I tried using the `$target` variable for the `"resume"` `$data` value, but that didn't seem to work either. As you can probably tell, I'm not exactly sure where this is going wrong (I'm a front-end developer out of my element :D).

Echoing `$data["resume"]` gives an Array, while echoing `$target` gives the location + name of the file, as expected. I guess I'm unsure **what** I need to be passing through in the `$data` array...Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here? If it helps, I get no error from Lever when submitting. In fact, it returns a 200 OK message and posts just fine, just without a resume field!

Answer (score 1):

You can do that like this

```
$localFile = $_FILES[$fileKey]['tmp_name']; 

$fp = fopen($localFile, 'r');

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'someurl' . $strFileName); //$strFileName is obvious
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 86400);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, 'CURL_callback');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE, 128);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($localFile));
curl_exec ($ch);

if (curl_errno($ch)) {

    $msg = curl_error($ch);
}
else {

    $msg = 'File uploaded successfully.';
}

curl_close ($ch);

$return = array('msg' => $msg);

echo json_encode($return);
```

Comment: Thanks! I messed around with that for a while, but eventually found that WordPress has a nice HTTP API with a `wp_remote_post` method. That paired with this article solved my issue http://codechutney.com/posting-file-using-wp_remote_post/