# POST file Curl Commandline to PHP Curl

Tags: php, api, rest, audio, curl

We are trying to convert use the following curl cmdline which is working fine

```
curl --request POST --data-binary @"/home/project/enrol/my.wav" --header "Content-Type:audio/wav" --header "VsitEmail: 200037test2@test.com" --header "VsitPassword: 8270f2824111e04d9278c01a92b388147d9d02e0b50d946d25d00db375ff1282" --header "VsitDeveloperId: 200037" https://siv.voiceprintportal.com/sivservice/api/enrollments
```

to PHP libcurl which is constantly giving internal error.

Please suggest where i am wrong .

Code

```
$ch = curl_init();

$path="/home/project/enrol/my.wav";

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: audio/wav","VsitEmail: 200037test2@test.com","VsitPassword: 8270f2824111e04d9278c01a92b388147d9d02e0b50d946d25d00db375ff1282","VsitDeveloperId: 200037"));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

curl_setopt( $ch , CURLOPT_VERBOSE , 0 );

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,array('file' => '@'.$path));

$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);

print_r($result);
```

**Update 1**

```
$localfile='/home/project/enrol/my.wav';
$url = 'https://siv.voiceprintportal.com/sivservice/api/enrollments';

$ch = curl_init();
$fields = array('file' => '@' .$localfile);

$resource = curl_init();

curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
//curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: 
audio/wav","VsitEmail: 200037test2@test.com","VsitPassword: 8270f2824111e04d9278c01a92b388147d9d02e0b50d946d25d00db375ff1282","VsitDeveloperId: 200037"));
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
//$result = json_decode(curl_exec($resource));
$result=curl_exec($resource);
curl_close($resource);

echo "The result is";

print_r($result);
```

Comment: Check the following answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/28637283/1061944

Comment: that is the upload and REST server doesnt support .Probably I am not getting the right way of using the --data-binary @"/home/project/enrol/my.wav" in PHP Curl

Comment: you haven't set headers in your PHP CURL code.

Comment: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: audio/wav","VsitEmail: 200037test2@test.com","VsitPassword: 8270f2824111e04d9278c01a92b388147d9d02e0b50d946d25d00db375ff1282","VsitDeveloperId: 200037"))  Should It be differently ?

Answer (score 0):

Check the following code

```
$url = 'http://google.com';
$header = array('Content-Type: multipart/form-data');
$fields = array('file' => '@' . $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][0]);

$resource = curl_init();
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
$result = curl_exec($resource);
curl_close($resource);
```

Comment: I changed the $fields to localfile name and replaced the HTTPHEADER with my code . it is giving the same error internal server error.

Comment: update your question with updated code, with error you are getting. If you past the screenshot of the error you are getting.

Comment: Internal Server error mostly means you have an error in your code. some syntax or logic

Comment: I have updated your answer with the edited code . Somehow couldnt upload the screenshot as it is giving the credits error.

Comment: Always update you code in your question, not in someones answer. by the way I have updated your question

Answer (score 0):

It got resolved by passing the raw data file instead of an array. Correct code is

```
$localfile='@/home/project/enrol/my.wav';
$url = 'https://siv.voiceprintportal.com/sivservice/api/enrollments';
$data = file_get_contents('/home/project/enrol/my.wav');
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'X-Requested-With: JSONHttpRequest';
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: audio/wav';
$headers[] = 'VsitEmail: 200037test2@test.com';
$headers[] = 'VsitPassword: 8270f2824111e04d9278c01a92b388147d9d02e0b50d946d25d00db375ff1282';
$headers[] = 'VsitDeveloperId: 200037';
$resource = curl_init();
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);
$result = json_decode(curl_exec($resource));
curl_close($resource);
echo "The result is";
print_r($result);
```